# Interpreting Binomial CDF results

Tags: binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a Binomial distribution CDF, and was trying to interpret the results. For this, I have $n=100$ trials, with $p=0.25$. When computing the CDF, I have:

$P(X \leq 25) = 0.5535$

Does this mean that the probability of obtaining $\leq$ 25 successes in 100 trials is 55.35%. Further, if I was to compute:

$1 - P(X \leq 25)  = 0.446$,

Does this mean that the probability of obtaining **more** than 25 successes in 100 trials is 44.6%?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking what a CDF means?  What your probability statements mean?  What percentages are?  Since everything you write is correct, it is difficult to determine what you're trying to ask!

Comment: Sorry! yes, i just realized that. I guess I'm trying to understand the intutition behind having more than 25 successes in 100 trials, since the expected value is 25. This is saying there is for example a 44.6% probability of having 90 successes (i.e., more than 25?)

Comment: I find it helpful in such cases to contemplate the simplest examples.  For instance, consider $n=2$ and $p=0.5,$ with an expected value of $1:$ here, $\Pr(X\le 1)=0.75$ is far from $1/2.$  Given any random variable $X$ with expectation $\mu,$ there's nothing you can say in general about $\Pr(X\le\mu)$ except that it cannot be zero--but it could be literally any positive number less than $1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=.25),$ then you say $$P(X > 25) =
1 - P(X \le 25) = 0.4465,$$ to four places. This is the probability
that some one of the values 26 through 100 will occur. In particular,
one of these values is 90; its share of that overall probability is
$P(X = 90) \approx 0$ (positive but very tiny). [Using R, were a binomial PDF is `dbinom` and CDF is `pbinom`.]

```
1 - pbinom(25, 100, .25)
[1] 0.4465292
dbinom(90, 100, .25)
[1] 6.360895e-43
```

It may help your intuition to recall that $X$ is approximately normal
with $\mu = E(X) = np = 25$ and $\sigma = SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} =  4.3301.$

[image]

R code for figure.

```
x = 0:100;  PDF = dbinom(x, 100, 0.25)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(100, .25) [blue bars] with Approximating Normal Density"
plot(x, PDF,  type="h", col="blue", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, 25, 4.3301), add=T, col="maroon", lwd=2)
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
```